# Escape nonbreaking space as argument in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I want to filter out empty records, but I am not able to remove the records which has no data but a series of space..

I have a Entity A with attribute "name" . I want to query all those objects of Entity A which has some text value for attribute name and not "series of space",In other words I need to incorporate this in the query -->

```
[name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet].length!=0
```

But all I could was check the length of string INCLUDING the whitespace which is not right.
I am using-->

```
     NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name!=' ' or name.length!=0 "];
```

Your suggetions are welcome.

Comment: What exactly do the records look like that you want to filter out? Do you really mean a "non-breaking space" (Unicode U+00A0)?

Answer (score 0):

you can trim the string and check for the lenght of the string like this:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [aRecordString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]]];

if (trimmedString.lenght > 0) {

    // the string if valid or at least is not just a spaces string
}
else {

    // the string is not valid or was just a spaces string
}
```

so if you want to apply this check in a predicate you can use a predicate with block:

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

        // do your checks here and return TRUE or FALSE if the ovject match your criteria
}];
```

Comment: Block-based predicates cannot be used in a Core Data fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove objects where a specific string attribute contains only spaces, use a regex-based predicate, and then delete whatever objects you find.

A fetch with a predicate like this would find all of those objects:

```
NSPredicate *reqPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attributeName matches ' +'"];
```

Once found, use `-[NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:]` to delete the resulting objects.